# `convert_time_zone` function to retrieve the values based on the timezone specified for each row in Polars

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-polars

I'm attempting to determine the time based on the timezone specified in each row using `Polars`. Consider the following code snippet:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "time": [datetime(2023, 4, 3, 2), datetime(2023, 4, 4, 3), datetime(2023, 4, 5, 4)],
    "tzone": ["Asia/Tokyo", "America/Chicago", "Europe/Paris"]
}).with_columns(c.time.dt.replace_time_zone("UTC"))

df.with_columns(
    tokyo=c.time.dt.convert_time_zone("Asia/Tokyo").dt.hour(),
    chicago=c.time.dt.convert_time_zone("America/Chicago").dt.hour(),
    paris=c.time.dt.convert_time_zone("Europe/Paris").dt.hour()
)
```

In this example, I've computed the time separately for each timezone to achieve the desired outcome, which is [11, 22, 6], corresponding to the hour of the `time` column according to the `tzone` timezone. Even then it is difficult to collect the information from the correct column.

Unfortunately, the following simple attempt to dynamically pass the timezone from the `tzone` column directly into the `convert_time_zone` function does not work:

```py
df.with_columns(c.time.dt.convert_time_zone(c.tzone).dt.hour())
#TypeError: argument 'time_zone': 'Expr' object cannot be converted to 'PyString'
```

What would be the most elegant approach to accomplish this task?

Comment: Its not super elegant but an alternative to using the `polars-xdt` plugin would be to combine the resulting columns using an `pl.when().then().otherwise()` construct. This seems feasible if the number of unique time zones is small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this which fully works with lazy execution is to use the `polars-xdt` plugin:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": [
            datetime(2023, 4, 3, 2),
            datetime(2023, 4, 4, 3),
            datetime(2023, 4, 5, 4),
        ],
        "tzone": ["Asia/Tokyo", "America/Chicago", "Europe/Paris"],
    }
).with_columns(pl.col("time").dt.replace_time_zone("UTC"))

df.with_columns(
    result=xdt.to_local_datetime("time", pl.col("tzone")).dt.hour(),
)
```

Result:

```
Out[6]:
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────────────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────┐
│ time                    ┆ tzone           ┆ result │
│ ---                     ┆ ---             ┆ ---    │
│ datetime[μs, UTC]       ┆ str             ┆ i8     │
╞═════════════════════════╪═════════════════╪════════╡
│ 2023-04-03 02:00:00 UTC ┆ Asia/Tokyo      ┆ 11     │
│ 2023-04-04 03:00:00 UTC ┆ America/Chicago ┆ 22     │
│ 2023-04-05 04:00:00 UTC ┆ Europe/Paris    ┆ 6      │
└─────────────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────┘
```

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars-xdt

If you don't need lazy execution, then as other answers have suggested, you can iterate over the unique values of your `'time_zone'` column

Answer (score 4):

As @Hericks has mentioned in the comments, you can use multiple when/then conditions:

```py
df.with_columns(
   pl.when(c.tzone == tzone)
     .then(c.time.dt.convert_time_zone(tzone).dt.hour())
     .alias(tzone.rsplit("/", 1)[1].lower())
   for tzone in df.get_column("tzone").unique()
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 5)
┌─────────────────────────┬─────────────────┬───────┬─────────┬───────┐
│ time                    ┆ tzone           ┆ tokyo ┆ chicago ┆ paris │
│ ---                     ┆ ---             ┆ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---   │
│ datetime[μs, UTC]       ┆ str             ┆ i8    ┆ i8      ┆ i8    │
╞═════════════════════════╪═════════════════╪═══════╪═════════╪═══════╡
│ 2023-04-03 02:00:00 UTC ┆ Asia/Tokyo      ┆ 11    ┆ null    ┆ null  │
│ 2023-04-04 03:00:00 UTC ┆ America/Chicago ┆ null  ┆ 22      ┆ null  │
│ 2023-04-05 04:00:00 UTC ┆ Europe/Paris    ┆ null  ┆ null    ┆ 6     │
└─────────────────────────┴─────────────────┴───────┴─────────┴───────┘
```

[`pl.coalesce()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.coalesce.html#polars.coalesce) can be used to create a single column instead.

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.coalesce(
       pl.when(c.tzone == tzone)
         .then(c.time.dt.convert_time_zone(tzone).dt.hour())
       for tzone in df.get_column("tzone").unique()
    )
    .alias("hour")
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────────────────────────┬─────────────────┬──────┐
│ time                    ┆ tzone           ┆ hour │
│ ---                     ┆ ---             ┆ ---  │
│ datetime[μs, UTC]       ┆ str             ┆ i8   │
╞═════════════════════════╪═════════════════╪══════╡
│ 2023-04-03 02:00:00 UTC ┆ Asia/Tokyo      ┆ 11   │
│ 2023-04-04 03:00:00 UTC ┆ America/Chicago ┆ 22   │
│ 2023-04-05 04:00:00 UTC ┆ Europe/Paris    ┆ 6    │
└─────────────────────────┴─────────────────┴──────┘
```

Comment: nice - might be worth mentioning that this only works in eager mode? else `df.get_column("tzone")` will raise

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this without an extra plugin is to split up the source by the tzone so that you can extract it as a unique value.

If you're starting from eager then use `partition_by` like this:

```
pl.concat([
    df_inner.lazy().with_columns(
        hour=pl.col('time')
        .dt.replace_time_zone('UTC')
        .dt.convert_time_zone(x[0])
        .dt.hour())
        for x,df_inner in df.with_row_index('__i').partition_by(['tzone'], as_dict=True).items()
]).sort('__i').drop('__i').collect()
```

It makes the internal frame lazy so that the `concat` will do all the time zone operations in parallel when it collects.

If you're starting from lazy then you can do

```
(
    df.lazy()
    .with_row_index('__i')
    .group_by('tzone')
    .map_groups(lambda df : (
        df.with_columns(
            hour=pl.col('time')
                .dt.replace_time_zone('UTC')
                .dt.convert_time_zone(df['tzone'][0])
                .dt.hour())
        ), schema={'time':pl.Datetime, 'tzone':pl.String, 'hour':pl.Int8, '__i':pl.UInt32})
    .sort('__i')
    .drop('__i')
    .collect()
    )
```

but it's much slower than the first approach as it doesn't do the groups in parallel.

Comment: You can use `.group_by(['tzone'])` instead of `partition_by().items()`